# Pass Information From VBS to Visual Basic Application?

Tags: vb.net, vbscript, active-directory

I want to run a vbs from a Visual Basic application and return the string back to the vb app. Google isn't hitting on much. Here is the vbs I want to run, and I want to pass the "ou" information back to the Visual Basic application as a string.

```
OPTION EXPLICIT
DIM objNetwork
DIM computerName
DIM ou

' Get the computerName of PC
set objNetwork = createobject("Wscript.Network")
'computerName = objNetwork.ComputerName
computername = Inputbox("Enter the network name of the PC to find :")

' Call function to find OU from computer name
ou = getOUByComputerName(computerName)

IF ou = "" THEN ou = "Not Found"

wscript.echo ou


function getOUByComputerName(byval computerName)
    ' *** Function to find ou/container of computer object from computer name ***

    DIM namingContext, ldapFilter, ou
    DIM cn, cmd, rs
    DIM objRootDSE

    ' Bind to the RootDSE to get the default naming context for
 ' the domain.  e.g. dc=HCHS,dc=co,dc=uk
 set objRootDSE = getobject("LDAP://RootDSE")
    namingContext = objRootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")
    set objRootDSE = nothing

    ' Construct an ldap filter to search for a computer object
 ' anywhere in the domain with a name of the value specified.
    ldapFilter = "<LDAP://" & namingContext & _
    ">;(&(objectCategory=Computer)(name=" & computerName & "))" & _
    ";distinguishedName;subtree"

    ' Standard ADO code to query database
 set cn = createobject("ADODB.Connection")
    set cmd = createobject("ADODB.Command")

    cn.open "Provider=ADsDSOObject;"
    cmd.activeconnection = cn
    cmd.commandtext = ldapFilter

    set rs = cmd.execute

    if rs.eof <> true and rs.bof <> true then
        ou = rs(0)
        ' Convert distinguished name into OU.
 ' e.g. cn=CLIENT01,OU=HCHS_Computers,dc=HCHS,dc=co,dc=uk
 ' to: OU=HCHS_Computers,dc=HCHS,dc=co,dc=uk
        ou = mid(ou,instr(ou,",")+1,len(ou)-instr(ou,","))
        getOUByComputerName = ou

    end if

    rs.close
    cn.close


end function
```

Comment: Why not just port the VBScript to VB.Net? It's only late-bound COM calls. Should be easy enough.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the ScriptControl?

See here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227413(v=vs.60)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/184740

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/184739

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/make-your-vb-apps-scriptable-with-the-microsoft-windows-script-control/1045808